# Location of index.html file in jboss server

Tags: jboss

I'm curious to how someone could access the index.html file in a jboss application through the server hosting the jboss app.

Comment: More details are needed here. What kind of index file? From a deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. 
You can read using read-content(path=file) to read the index.html on JBoss using cli commands, but not exactly the content.

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /deployment=hibernate.war:read-content(path=index.html)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {"uuid" => "06519ccf-24d4-4b6f-9be1-aa859f98a538"},
    "response-headers" => {"attached-streams" => [{
        "uuid" => "06519ccf-24d4-4b6f-9be1-aa859f98a538",
        "mime-type" => "text/html"
    }]}
}
```

To see the content, it will necessary to do the following:

```
attachment display --operation=/deployment=hibernate.war:read-content(path=index.html)
```

That will show you the content as in:

```
<!-- Plain HTML page that kicks us into the app -->

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=index.jsf">
</head>
```

Furthermore, you can do that with any file and you can even add content to you deployment.

Finally, you can get several info from the deployment but mostly meta-info:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deployment-info 
NAME          RUNTIME-NAME  PERSISTENT ENABLED STATUS 
hibernate.war hibernate.war false      true    OK
```